# Halachic opinions on tefillin peshutim

Tags: halacha, history, tefilin, acharonim

I was discussing the subject of tefillin with my father motzei-Shabbat and particular, the *battim* (leather boxes that contain the *parshiyot*, or parchment scrolls). We ended up wondering what the mid-to-late 20th century Acharonim, in particular those with a more "modern-Orthodox" background, preferred in regards to the use of *tefillin peshutim* in the modern era, when better forms of *battim* are available. We also wondered on the opinion of R' Moshe Feinstein זצ”ל, as his teshuvot are often used as a yardstick to measure others.

Modern- and Neo-Orthoodox opinions (if they exist):

- The Rav זצ”ל
- R' Amital זצ”ל
- R' Michael Melchior שליט”א
- R' Aharon Lichtenstein זצ”ל
- R' Norman Lamm שליט”א
- R' Teitz (rabbinic family from Elizabeth, R' Pinchas, זצ”ל or R' Elazar Mayer, שליט”א in particular)
- R' Josef Breuer זצ”ל, rav of KAJ/Washington Heights and former head of the Frankfurt Realschüle

Comment: What would be the advantage of peshutim?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, the only advantage I know of is cost (and if the battim are destroyed, they're less expensive to replace, assuming the parshiot are still kosher).

Comment: OTOH, Gassos are fixable if damaged, so they may not need replacement

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I don't disagree. The issue behind this is that I'm looking into buying new tefillin, however my father (who is fromm) is a bit skittish about the battim making up about half the price (they're not the most expensive) even if he isn't paying for them. So we're looking for halachic opinions.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Indeed, it does seem that many are so concerned with the battim they end up spending less than they should on the most important part of tefillin - the parshiyos! I'd like dakkos battim with really nice parshiyos, you know?